# PHP jQuery HTML form insert to MySQL then stay on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a simple PHP intranet site where there is an HTML form that takes 2 input fields. I want to take the user input from the HTML form, insert the values into MySQL database, but keep the user's browser on the same page. I have a separate PHP file that does the MySQL INSERT. I have been trying to do this with both pure PHP, and with the help of jQuery, but I can't get it to work! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my HTML form (which is in a PHP file):

```
<form name ="form" action="" method="POST">
  Claim Title: <br>
  <input type="text" name="title" required>
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>

  Claim Body: <br>
  <textarea name="claim" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The PHP file that does the db processing is called db-insert.php:

```
<?php

    require 'connect.php';
    $conn = Connect();

    // Claim form and sql insert variables
    $title          = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $claim          = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['claim']);
    $claimInsert    = "INSERT INTO claims(claim_title,claim_body,claim_type) VALUES('" . $title . "','" . $claim . "','T');";
    $success        = $conn->query($claimInsert);

    $conn->close();

?>
```

The connect.php file:

```
<?php

    function Connect(){

        // Connection variables
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username   = "user";
        $password   = "password";
        $dbname     = "db";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);

        return $conn;
        }
?>
```

Finally the .js file that I've written (I use the term 'written' loosely as I obtained it from another StackOverflow page on something similar) is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("db-insert.php", function(data, status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "/nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm a bit of novice with jQuery/AJAX/related JavaScript and my PHP skills are growing but not amazing. I am using FireFox JavaScript debugger console and when I click the SUBMIT button for my form it isn't displaying anything, which makes me think it isn't processing the form data.

EDIT: I should have added this to underpin a comment made earlier in my post - I am in the early stages of dev work, please don't tell to parametrise and protect my SQL statements - I am aware of this :)

Comment: Nope, you have to post the form using AJAX,  `$.post(url, data, callback)` and not post it normally, `return false, on submit`

Comment: use `$.post()` instead of `$.get()`

Comment: for data you can use `$('form[name="form"]').serialize()` or build it manually.  And `$('form[name="form"]').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); return false; });`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main goal is to do this without changing or refreshing the page, you can use Ajax and jQuery like this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-my-form', function(){
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var claim = $("#claim").val();

      jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://your-site-url/db-insert.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {title: title, claim: claim},
        success: function(res) {
          if (res)
          {
            alert('Hurray! Successfully done');
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          if (xhr)
          {
            alert('There was an error');
           }
        }
      });
    });
```

You can also add code to receive the insert status and process it in the return section of the Ajax code. Modify your html code by adding id tags to the inputs like this:

```
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required>

    <textarea name="claim" id="claim" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name ="submit" id="submit-my-form" value="Submit"/>
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hi Edwin and thanks so much for this. It sort of works! Strange behavior; If I visit the page and fill out the form and click Submit then nothing happens in the db. If I click the Submit button a 2nd and then a 3rd time, only then does it insert a row into the db. Any ideas as to why it won't make an INSERT the first time?

Comment: Also, the alerts flash on and then off the screen so quickly I can't read them, I was hoping the alert would stay visible until the user clicks the 'OK' button, any ideas on this also?

Comment: From your comment, it seems to me you could either have a JS error  or an error from the PHP backend. To find out what the problem is, try this: If you use Chrome, right click on the browser window and click inspect on the popup menu. This will open the debug window below. Click on the Console tab. Should be the 3rd tab. This will open up a window where you can see any errors. To catch any errors from the PHP code, add this to success function in the Ajax call. console.log(res); On the error function, add console.log(xhr); Refresh page and run again with the debug window still open

Comment: If it works for you, do kindly accept my answer. Thank you

Comment: If I Submit via FireFox the data is not submitted. Using Chrome however it does submit the data to the db, however the JQuery alert says there is an error, even though the INSERT is made to the db.

Comment: That is why i showed you how to get the error in the browser console. You can share the error if you please so I can see what it is. You can also debug it in firefox, just like in Chrome

Comment: Thank you Edwin, your solution works really well. This is working fine. The problem I was having in Firefox caching responses. I have added some JS to disable caching of ajax responses, and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form[name="form"]').submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    /*
    you can put the url in the form action as normal, 
    its an old habit of mine, so if JavaScript is off on 
    the clients browser the form still works.
    */
    var url = $(this).attr('action'); 
    var iData = {
      title: $('input[name="title"]').val(),
      claim: $('textarea[name="claim"]').val()
    };
    
    console.log(url);
    console.log(iData);

    /*
     Obviously you're going to need to un-comment this,
     Ajax doesn't really work well on SO website

     $.post(url, iData, function(data){
      //do something on return
    });
    */
    
    //yea it's old school
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name ="form" action="db-insert.php" method="POST">
  Claim Title: <br>
  <input type="text" name="title" value="" required>
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>

  Claim Body: <br>
  <textarea name="claim" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post, however this doesn't work. I've tried editing your code here a few ways but can't get it to make an insert into the db. Any ideas as to what needs to be done?

Comment: Nope, you would have to check the browsers development console, typically its `f12` then you want too open the network tab ( or console tab ) and see what it says.  `This doesn't work` doesn't really tell me anything.

Comment: Like this `Finally the .js file that I've written` is it separate file then the file with the `form` and HTML.  If so are you including it `in the page header`, or is it in a `<script>` tag in the same page.  This is hard stuff, you need to be more specific. Generalizations don't do anything but cause frustration.  For all we know, the Javascript is fine and you have a 404 error or something like that.  There is like a zillion things that could be wrong.

Comment: Correct, I apologise that was an annoying response to send. Ok I changed serilize to serialize in your code. Nothing is displayed in the debugger console, nothing is inserted into the db. I don't know if this means that there is something wrong with the js, or something else. I'm looking at the various bits of code I have to try to establish where this is falling down.

Comment: Well, I updated it with a snip-it, that does work, provided the target page exists.  I'm telling you `F12` is your friend....  The debug window would show you if the request is triggered, or if there are any javascript errors.  You can also output to the console.  Just like in the above code.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the F12 debug console. I'm having a problem with the '//do something on return' line in your code. I'm not sure what needs to happen here. Running the code as-is, nothing is inserted into the db. The debugger shows that the variables are holding the correct data (form input).

Comment: the //do something is a callback that happens after the server request is done, your issue lies either in the post data being wrong or the script the form submits to being broken ( based on what you said )

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.post()` to send your data to `PHP`, and `preventDefault()` to prevent the page from reloading.

> [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) - Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.
>
> [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) - The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {title: $('#title').val(), claim: $('#claim').val()};
        console.log(data);
        // $.post("db-insert.php", data, function(data, status){
        //     alert("Data: " + data + "/nStatus: " + status);
        //     });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name ="form" action="" method="POST">
    Claim Title: <br>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" required>
    <span class="error">* </span>
    <br><br>

    Claim Body: <br>
    <textarea id="claim" name="claim" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <input id="sub" type="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then in your `db-insert.php`

```
    <?php
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $claim = $_POST['claim'];

    // rest of the code here
```

Answer (score 0):

hope can help u

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
    $("[name='submit']").click(function ()
    {
        sendS();
    });

});

function sendS()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"php.php",
        data:{title:$("[name='title']"),claim:$("[name='claim']")},

        success: function(data)
        {
            //display or do somethg
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () 
        {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    }); 
}



<?php
$data1=$_POST["title"];
$data2=$_POST["claim"];

echo "Title : ".$data1."<br> Claim : ".$data2;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, however this doesn't work. The form refreshes but nothing is written to the db.

Comment: this just a way to past u data by ajax to php , but it work for me